# How do I add a chain of trust with x509.CertificateBuilder?

Tags: python, cryptography, x509, python-cryptography

I'm building a certificate with [cryptography.x509.CertificateBuilder](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#x-509-certificate-builder):

```
from pathlib import Path
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import Encoding

private_key: rsa.RSAPrivateKey

ca_cert: x509.Certificate
ca_cert_private_key: rsa.RSAPrivateKey

cert = (
    x509.CertificateBuilder()
    .subject_name(x509.Name.from_rfc4514_string(f"CN={workstation_name}"))
    .issuer_name(ca_cert.subject)
    .public_key(private_key.public_key())
    .serial_number(x509.random_serial_number())
    .not_valid_before(today)
    .not_valid_after(today + timedelta(days=60))
    .add_extension(subject_alt_name, critical=False)
    .sign(ca_cert_private_key)
)
Path("workstation.crt").write_bytes(cert.public_bytes(Encoding.PEM))
```

How do I add the ca_cert to the [certificate chain](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_chains_and_cross-certification) for the cert I'm creating?

E.g. for stackoverflow, the cert looks like this, and you can see that there are 3 certs in the chain

```
$ openssl s_client -connect stackoverflow.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.stackexchange.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = *.stackexchange.com
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Dec 18 14:08:17 2022 GMT; NotAfter: Mar 18 14:08:16 2023 GMT
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
   i:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Sep  4 00:00:00 2020 GMT; NotAfter: Sep 15 16:00:00 2025 GMT
 2 s:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 4096 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Jan 20 19:14:03 2021 GMT; NotAfter: Sep 30 18:14:03 2024 GMT
---
```

For the cert I'm creating there is only 1 certificate in the chain. How do I add the ca_cert as the 2nd?

```
$ openssl s_client -connect localhost:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
Can't use SSL_get_servername
depth=1 CN = [Redacted CA Cert Name]
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = [Redacted Workstation Name]
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = [Redacted Workstation Name]
   i:CN = [Redacted CA Cert Name]
---
```

Comment: Without more context a certificate chain is just a concept. That is, the root CA starts the chain, the certificate the root CA signs is next, and each certificate in the chain is signed by the certificate that precedes it. In actual usage in TLS the certificates are sent in the opposite order, with the last certificate in the chain (the server certificate) sent first.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I've updated the question to try give more context

Comment: For TLS creating the cert chain is specific to whatever library or software you are using for TLS. Sometime it's a simple as concatenating the PEM encoded certs one after the other in a single file.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thanks. My questions is very specific that I'm trying to do this with the python cryptography library:

https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#x-509-certificate-builder

Comment: For what pupose?

Comment: I agree with James for above, but I'll sharpen the latest comment: which software are you using for the server? Because that defines what is expected for the certificate chain. Usually you'd use a PFX / PKCS#12 file for software defined keys.

Comment: I'm currently using lighttpd+mod_openssl.  I checked the docs and I see that they have the option "ca-file" that you can point to a PEM file with the CA in it. Thank you @MaartenBodewes

Comment: The python cryptography library has a feature to write PKCS#12 file with CAs in it.  https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.pkcs12.serialize_key_and_certificates